# Is it possible to bypass warmup?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Every competitive match starts with a "warmup" phase which generally lasts from two to four minutes (as the majority of players have low-end hardware and as a result take long to connect). The warmup stage can be described as a spawn-killing fest where almost in all instances multiple players manage to sneak to the enemy spawn zone and endlessly mow down opponents with automatic weapons and sniper rifles. I understand that completely skipping over warmup isn't possible without modifying server settings, but can players choose not to spawn before the match officially starts for example?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, the answer is no.

Like you said you have a 5 minute warm-up time so all the players can connect to the server, but that time is cut short when all players are connected. The timer then switches to a 60 second countdown. The server works in a specific way so by not spawning until the match starts the server would think you are either not connected or you are a spectator. And anyway there is no setting or preference for you to change either.

P.S. Connecting to the server is more of a network speed deal than hardware (though it does contribute). You can have an uber computer and a terrible internet service provider and still be the last one to connect to a server compared to someone on a non-gaming laptop with gigabit internet speeds.

Comment: Is the time left 10 seconds and not a minute when all players are connected? On official servers, the timer commonly "switches" to 60 seconds.

Comment: @user198327 I forget, I'm pretty sure it switches to 10 seconds. If someone could double check then edit the answer that would be great

Comment: Some "switch" certainly is to 60 seconds.